# Trying to remove information from a user profile

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to clean some information out of the user profiles in Google Apps via the Admin SDK. In below example I want to remove all websites listed in the profile. During the execution it all looks good and the result of the patch function shows the profile without the websites in it. (update function has similar results)

However when looking at the profile afterwards the websites are still there ?

What am I doing wrong ?

```
function cleanUserProfileTST()
{
  var userEmail = 'john.doe@mydomain.com'
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
  Logger.log (user);
  var websites = user.websites;
  delete user.websites;
  Logger.log (user);
  var result = AdminDirectory.Users.patch(user, userEmail);
  //var result = AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, userEmail);
  Logger.log(user);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `user.websites = ""` instead of completely leaving it out of the resource that goes back via patch / update